# Get Equation to generate data frame for graphing from user input

Tags: r, shiny

I am mapping out how I am going to create a shiny app which allows users to input parameters for an equation which depends on time. With the equation, I hope to then generate a data frame which can be graphed by ggplot.

I am not sure if this is practical and was wondering if anyone with more experience has insight on the matter.

Hi! So I have r shiny code which can take user input and save it as a csv file and a data frame. I am attempting to run a for loop which will iterate over time. For example:
shiny app asks user for values A and B,
takes those values and using the equation V=A*t+B, runs a for loop to gather data frame of t vs V data.

Then take that frame and graph it dynamically

Comment: Hi SoC, welcome to stack. Could you add to your question what have you tried/looked at so far?